# Can't connect to server on DigitalOcean?

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean

tell me please why I can't connect to my server from postman;
I'm connected to my droplet with SSH, and start my project from the terminal (node app.js). I see in the terminal that everything works fine and my project run on port 4200. But when I try to send a request to my server, Nothing happens.

For example, my server has IP 111.111.111.111, and in postman I use 111.111.111.111:4200/user/login but there is no result. 
When I do that request for the local project (http://localhost:4200/user/login) everything works fine.

Comment: Have you opened the ports?  `sudo ufw allow 4200`

Comment: Thanks, your comment solved the problem!